# how to format flot char yaxis by value seconds in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm working with highcharts char. I need to show the yaxis labels H:i:s time format(for ex. yaxis - 00:00:00, 00:05:00, 00:10:00 and etc.).

Here is my code (full code in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzjbb848/9/)):

```
LiveFeeds = {

    init: function(tab)
    {
        var tab = tab || '#calling-intensity';
        $(tab+'-chart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,minRange: 0.1,
                title: {
                    text: chartYaxis
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: {
                            x1: 0,
                            y1: 0,
                            x2: 0,
                            y2: 1
                        },
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    },
                    marker: {
                        radius: 2
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }
            },
            tooltip: tooltipData,
            series: seriesData
        });
    }

};
```

This is a example but on Flot chart https://jsfiddle.net/p41d165j/14/.

Comment: I don't understand "I need to show the yaxis H:i:s time format". You mean the labels? the tooltip?

Comment: yes, labels. With tooltip all its fine

Comment: but y axis labels would show the y value of the point, and x axis would show the date. Do you want date on both axes?

Answer (score 0):

Use http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter to format the labels as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

To change date format of labels you could use [`dateTimeLabelFormats`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats) like:

```
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    millisecond: '%H:%M:%S',
    second: '%H:%M:%S',
    minute: '%H:%M:%S',
    hour: '%H:%M:%S',
    day: '%H:%M:%S',
    week: '%H:%M:%S',
    month: '%H:%M:%S',
    year: '%H:%M:%S'
  },
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/hzjbb848/10/

Axis by default will display labels for each day, because of axis range, but if you zoom in - you will see hours.

You could consider using different format for `day` or use [`tickPositioner`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) to set ticks not on days.

To fully control what is displayed in axis labels set up [`formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter) function.